# ¿Cómo obtener correctamente delegación/alcaldía de CDMX con la API de Google maps?

Tags: json, api, google-maps, google-api

Estoy haciendo uso de la API de google maps para obtener direcciones por medio de un input,
y al introducir una dirección de Ciudad de México, no logro obtener correctamente la delegación de la CDMX, con el campo municipio me devuelve Ciudad de México, y al indagar un poco más en el request del API, en campos de la respuesta, formatteed_adress en una cadena de caracteres y en el campo de adr_address en una cadena con etiquetas html y un span con una clase llamada Region, y ahí sí viene (en ocasiones) la delegación/alcaldía, pero a veces vienen dos span con Region, la delegación y 'CDMX', PD. en address_components no viene nada relacionado a Region.

Obj devuelto en respuesta ejemplo, se esperaría obtener Delegación/Alcaldía Miguel Hidalgo:

```
{
  "address_components": [
    {
      "long_name": "945",
      "short_name": "945",
      "types": [
        "street_number"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Calle Lago Zurich",
      "short_name": "C. Lago Zurich",
      "types": [
        "route"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Francisco I. Madero",
      "short_name": "Francisco I. Madero",
      "types": [
        "sublocality_level_1",
        "sublocality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Ciudad de México",
      "short_name": "México D.F.",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Ciudad de México",
      "short_name": "CDMX",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Mexico",
      "short_name": "MX",
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "11480",
      "short_name": "11480",
      "types": [
        "postal_code"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "adr_address": "<span class=\"street-address\">C. Lago Zurich 945</span>, <span class=\"extended-address\">Francisco I. Madero</span>, <span class=\"region\">Miguel Hidalgo</span>, <span class=\"postal-code\">11480</span> <span class=\"locality\">Ciudad de México</span>, <span class=\"region\">CDMX</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">Mexico</span>",
  "formatted_address": "C. Lago Zurich 945, Francisco I. Madero, Miguel Hidalgo, 11480 Ciudad de México, CDMX, Mexico",
  "geometry": {
    "location": {},
    "viewport": {
      "Va": {
        "lo": 19.4449116697085,
        "hi": 19.44760963029151
      },
      "Ka": {
        "lo": -99.2040725302915,
        "hi": -99.20137456970849
      }
    }
  },
  "name": "C. Lago Zurich 945",
  "types": [
    "street_address"
  ],
  "url": "https://maps.google.com/?q=C.+Lago+Zurich+945,+Francisco+I.+Madero,+Miguel+Hidalgo,+11480+Ciudad+de+M%C3%A9xico,+CDMX,+Mexico&ftid=0x85d20211947b70c7:0x765830c4f22c37bb",
  "vicinity": "Francisco I. Madero",
  "html_attributions": [],
  "utc_offset_minutes": -360
}
```

Se obtiene desde Angular, por medio de un Auto-complete haciendo uso de ngx-google-places-autocomplete, con librerías ngx-google-places-autocomplete, @types/googlemaps y agm-direction:

```
<input class="autocomplete-input" [ngClass]="darkMode ? 'dark-input': 'normal-input'"
                    ngx-google-places-autocomplete [options]='options' #placesRef="ngx-places"
                    (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)" />
```

Ojalá alguien haya logrado solucionar ese inconveniente, y me pueda apoyar.Muchas gracias!

Comment: Como tienes el llamado a la API?

Comment: Es en Angular haciendo uso de librerías agm-direction y ngx-google-places-autocomplete, ya edité la pregunta

Comment: @vmporcayom eres usuario desde hace casi 5 años, deberías saber que el código debe ir en texto y no en imágenes. Seria buena idea hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask].

Comment: @OCHOA ¡Gracias, por tu aporte!, ya lo puse en código, ya tienes capacidad de ayuda real?

Answer (score 1):

Tuve el mismo problema, la verdad por más que busque no encontré, yo lo solucioné usando el formatted_address haciendole un split(",") y en ese array en la posición 2 encontramos ese dato de la delegación usualmente (en las pruebas que hice en todas me trajo esa info, más no puedo asegurar) por lo que hay que validar que mínimo el array que devuelve el split sea de tamaño 3 o mayor, lo demás sí use el address_component normal como lo plasma googel en la documentación.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/400075)